# how to internationalize error messages in javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, atg-dynamo

Our requirement is to internationalize the already running site which is using ATG framework. We have implemented the same in our JSP, however, we have static error/informative messages in javascript. We need to translate the messages as well.

Please suggest how can we translate the messages. For JSP, we declared translations in a property file and reading from there.

Comment: I don't think there is a whole lot you can do wrong here. What approach were you thinking about?

Answer (score 1):

We have somewhat similar requirement for which we have used jstl. It might help you :

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %> 
<%@ page import="java.util.ResourceBundle"%>
```

Then under `<head> <fmt:setBundle basename="global-messages" />` 
Set bundle takes name of the property file. global-messages-en or global-messages-hi are the property files which will contain labels of respective languages. We have custom implementation for that.

```
<title><fmt:message key="parameter.page.title"/></title>
<h1> here key="parameter.page.title" will be replaced by corresponding value of that key</h1>
</head>
```

Comment: We have already implemented the approach in JSP using resource bundle. We need to translate the messages in javascript.

Comment: Do you want translator in JavaScript? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Zenith instead of using a translator .you can store the messages in json and display it when needed.

Comment: We created a jsp where we declared variables in json and loaded the file from script. Thanks @Manoj